# How to set all found list words values at once in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, list, match

I have a class as such:

```
    public class cls_words : IEquatable<cls_words>
    {
        public int indx { get; set; }
        public string wordTxt { get; set; }
        public int wordIsFound { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "ID: " + wordIsFound + "   Name: " + wordTxt;
        }
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null) return false;
            cls_words objAsWord = obj as cls_words;
            if (objAsWord == null) return false;
            else return Equals(objAsWord);
        }
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return wordIsFound;
        }

        public bool Equals(cls_words other)
        {
            if (other == null) return false;
            return (this.wordIsFound.Equals(other.wordIsFound));
        }
    }
```

Basically the class is a word, and whether or not it has been found in a search.

So I create a list of this class as such:

```
List<cls_words> wordsIn = new List<cls_words>();

wordsIn.Add(new cls_words { indx= 1, wordTxt = "test", wordIsFound=0 });
wordsIn.Add(new cls_words { indx= 2, wordTxt = "the", wordIsFound=0 });
wordsIn.Add(new cls_words { indx= 3, wordTxt = "test", wordIsFound=0 });
```

Then when I search the list to see if it contains a word, I want to set all wordIsFound values to 1 where appropriate. Some words in the list might be the same.

So something like

```
string wordSearch = "test";

if (wordsIn.Exists(x => x.wordTxt == wordSearch)) {

   //set all wordIsFound = 1 where word matches wordSearch 

}
```

So how would I set wordIsFound to 1 on the 1st and 3rd item in the list (the ones that match the wordSearch ?

Comment: This logic has no sense, why would you "save" into a variable if a word has a value instead of checking it?

Comment: `foreach(cls_words cw in wordsIn) cw.wordIsFound = wordsIn.Count(x=> x.wordTxt == cw.wordTxt)-1;`  or `foreach(cls_words cw in wordsIn) cw.wordIsFound = wordsIn.Count(x=> x.wordTxt .Equals(cw.wordTxt))-1;`

Answer (score 0):

```
string wordSearch = "test";
 foreach (cls_words clsword in wordsIn) {
   if(cls_word.wordTxt == wordSearch) {
      clsword.wordIsFound = 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: that is the best/only way? in a loop?

Comment: thx for the replies, I thought there might be a more elegant way than a loop. For example, the line:

```
if (wordsIn.Exists(x => x.wordTxt == wordSearch)) {
```

....checks all words without it being a loop. I know behind the scenes it has to loop, but I thought there might be similar code for setting. I guess not.

Comment: @E.D. yes. There is a ForEach function but internally does the same with less performance and legibility:S

Answer (score 0):

Easier approach might be to use a HashSet with your type (or even just a `string`).

```
HashSet<string> foundWords = new HashSet<string>();
HashSet<string> allWords = new HashSet<string>(); 
allWords.Add("test"); 
allWords.Add("apple");
allWords.Add("test"); // This will just "fail silently" if the word is already in the allWords HashSet.

// then to test:
string wordSearch = "test";
if (allWords.Contains(wordSearch)) foundWords.Add(wordSearch);

// you can even loop over your input of a very big string with something like:
string bigString = "this is a long string with many words";
int maxWords = 1000;
string[] allWordsToTest = bigString.Split(' ', maxWords);
foreach (string s in allWordsToTest)
    if (allWords.Contains(s)) foundWords.Add(s);
```

Obviously you're going to want to do some processing (set the words to a consistent case, empty the "found set" between trials, etc), but that should get you started.